# Need help making videos appear in a grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place 6 videos in a grid with 2 rows with 3 videos per row. I am able to do this with one row but cannot seem to find a way to do it with 2.

My current code for the videos is:

```
<div class="videos1">
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
        Coming Soon!
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>     <br>
      <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
        Coming Soon!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video1">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="video" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <div class="caption" style="color:#ffffff">
        Coming Soon!
      </div>
    </div>
```

My css code is:

```
.videos1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    gap: 50;
    
}
.video1 {
    width: 32%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    
    
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use css [grids](https://grid.layoutit.com).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: ". . ." ". . .";
}

.container > div {
  background-color: lime;
}

div:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>video 1</div>
  <div>video 2</div>
  <div>video 3</div>
  <div>video 4</div>
  <div>video 5</div>
  <div>video 6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the original grid: a table -- but not exactly a `<table>`. For a layout solution `<table>` and table tags (`<tr>`, `<th>`, `<td>`, etc.) are [discouraged for many reasons](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-tables-markup-a-website), but other tags that are assigned CSS property `display` with the values of `table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`, etc. are considered valid and acceptable (see **Figure I** and this [article](https://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero)).

**Figure I**

| HTML Tag | CSS |
| --- | --- |
| table | display: table |
| tr | display: table-row |
| thead | display: table-header-group |
| tbody | display: table-row-group |
| tfoot | display: table-footer-group |
| col | display: table-column |
| colgroup | display: table-column-group |
| td, th | display: table-cell |
| caption | display: table-caption |

Here's a simple example using [semantic tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics)

```css
/* Behave like a real <table> */
main {
  display: table;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

/* Behave like a real <tr> */
section {
  display: table-row;
}

/* Behave like a real <td> */
figure {
  display: table-cell;
}

/* Not required (optional) */
figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <iframe src="https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
      <figcaption>Dizzy</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <iframe src="https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
      <figcaption>Dizzy</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <iframe src="https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
      <figcaption>Dizzy</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <iframe src="https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
      <figcaption>Dizzy</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <iframe src="https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
      <figcaption>Dizzy</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <iframe src="https://bestvpn.org/html5demos/assets/dizzy.mp4" width="160" height="90"></iframe>
      <figcaption>Dizzy</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</main>
```